# Sort array into alternating smallest largest values?

Tags: php, arrays

Does anyone know how to sort an array into alternating smallest largest values?

I.E.

```
Array (10, 2, 5, 1, 30, 1, 7)
```

Should be :

```
(30, 1, 10, 1, 7, 2, 5)
```

EDIT:

Forgot to mention the arrays are associative, so:

```
Array("A"=>10, "B"=>2, "C"=>5, "D"=>1, "E"=>30, "F"=>1, "G"=>7)
```

Should become:

```
("E"=>30, "D"=>1, "A"=>10, "F"=>1, "G"=>7, "B"=>2, "C"=>5)
```

Comment: Looks like largest/smallest rather than smallest/largest to me - do you want the smalles as the first element or the largest?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Sort your array then push elements from beginning and end of the array alternatively:

```
<?php

    $myArray = array(10, 2, 5, 1, 30, 1, 7);
    sort($myArray );
    $count=sizeof($myArray );

    $result= array();
    
    for($counter=0; $counter * 2 < $count; $counter++){

         array_push($result, $myArray[$count - $counter - 1]);
         //check if same elements (when the count is odd)
         if ($counter != $count - $counter - 1) {
             array_push($result, $myArray[$counter]);
         }

    }
    print_r ($result);

?>
```

returns:

```
Array ( [0] => 30 [1] => 1 [2] => 10 [3] => 1 [4] => 7 [5] => 2 [6] => 5 )
```

Comment: $myArray = array(10, 2, 5, 1, 30, 1, 7);
sort($myArray);

$newArray = array();
while (!empty($myArray)) {
    $newArray[] = array_shift($myArray);
    if (!empty($myArray))
        $newArray[] = array_pop($myArray);
}
var_dump($newArray);

Comment: it's your logic, but it just seemed simpler code than your use of counters

Answer (score 0):

There is no predefined way to do this.  However, php allows for a user sort function [`usort`](http://no.php.net/manual/en/function.usort.php)  which you can customise to sort the array in the way you require.

Answer (score 0):

I can't tell you the exact syntax, my php is very rusty, but what you can do:

- Sort your array in descending order
- Split in in half, let say array A and B;
- Create a new array and add each element from A and B in order `$A[i], $B[count($B)-1-i]`

This should give you what you need

Answer (score 0):

```
<?php
$x = array(10, 2, 5, 1, 30, 1, 7);

// First sort
sort($x);

// Then pick highest and lowest from the back and front of the array
// until it is empty.
$z = array();
while (count($x) > 0){
    $z[] = array_pop($x);
    if (count($x) > 0) // <- For arrays with an odd number of elements.
      $z[] = array_shift($x);
}

var_dump($z);
```

Answer (score 0):

$arr = [2,10,11,12,4,18];

```
$final_arr = [];
$max = $min = '';
for($i =0 ;$i <=count($arr);$i++){
    $max = max($arr);
    $final_arr[] = $max;
    $index = array_search($max, $arr);
    unset($arr[$index]);
    $min = min($arr);
    $final_arr[] = $min;
    $index = array_search($min, $arr);
    unset($arr[$index]);
}
print_r($final_arr);
```